# Gravity, planetary orbits

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, orbital-motion

If a planet was slowed down, what effect would it have on it’s orbit around a star. Or adversely if it were speeded up what effect would that have ?

Comment: What kind of effects so you think would happen?

Comment: I see no attempt at researching this issue, so I'm voting to close.  If you want it to stay open, you should do some searching and see if there is something that already exists that answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

if you slow the orbiting planet down, it will move closer to the star it is orbiting around, and pick up orbital speed as it does. If you speed it up in its orbit, it will move out farther away from the star and slow down as it does.

Comment: Thanks Niels. Would the ellipse shape of the orbit remain the same if slowed, only get smaller or would that differ ?

Comment: Also ! Sorry if it sounds naive.....but would it require a significant change in speed to either send it hurtling out into space or spiralling down into it’s star ?

Comment: Yes, to both. the rockets required to boost the satelllite out and away are large. Bringing the satellite down to earth requires a large rocket to "put the brakes on".

Comment: Sorry I wasn’t looking for the amount of force required to slow or increase a planet down, which I understand would be immense. I asked firstly in the event of a planet being slowed would the orbit shape remain the same or not. Secondly would it require a significant change in speed to knock it out of orbit entirely?